# Uploading base64 images to Google Cloud Storage using firebase-admin package in nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I have a function in nodejs backend where I wish to upload images (base64 images) to my google cloud storage using firebase-admin package. I followed the documentation on adding a service account key to allow access and upload to the storage but I get an error whenever I try. I used the file.save() method but no success with error "Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token: read ECONNRESET".

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
    const downloadUrls = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < imageFiles.length; index++) {
        const image = imageFiles[index];
        const encode_img = `data:image/jpeg;base64,${image}`;
        const imageBuffer = Buffer.from(encode_img, 'base64');
        console.log(imageBuffer);

        const file = bucket.file(`users/${v4()}.png`);

        console.log(file);

        file.save(imageBuffer, {
            metadata: { contentType: 'image/png', cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000', },
            public: true,
            gzip: true,
        }, ((error) => {

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);

                // return res.status(500).send('Unable to upload the image.');
            }
            console.log('done');

            // return res.status(200).send('Uploaded');
        }));
      }
```

[image: This is the error message I get.]